# Azure Pack remote console connect, failed to download RDP

Tags: azure, rdp, azure-pack

I am trying to do a POC on the azure pack and been trying to make remote console connect feature work. But unfortunately, it fails with unable to download RDP file error.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to get the installation and configuration right, as detailed in this official doc: [Remote Console in System Center 2012 R2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/system-center/system-center-2012-R2/dn469415(v=sc.12)), especially the cert generation and configuration part.

Some troubleshooting guidance is given here in this blog post, that talks some about common misconfigurations: [Troubleshooting Windows Azure Pack Console Connect](http://www.miru.ch/troubleshooting-windows-azure-pack-console-connect/)

Here are other solutions with detailed discussion that worked for some:

- [VM Console Connect prompt to download .JSON file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/e31ab1ff-39d3-4de1-be55-679159c3cf28/vm-console-connect-prompt-to-download-json-file?forum=windowsazurepack)
- [Azure Pack Console Connect failed](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/334283bf-683f-48c9-b5dd-97eea2932cab?category=windowsazurepack)